# Could not access KVM kernel module while building SONiC NOS on vm with vagrant

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization, vagrant

I'm trying to build sonic build image for virtual switch from https://github.com/Azure/sonic-buildimage on ubuntu 16.04/xenial vm with vagrant, but I've got an error:

```
++ on_error
++ echo '============= kvm_log =============='
============= kvm_log ==============
++ cat /tmp/tmp.3CIfxaYzCK
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
+ on_exit
+ rm -f /tmp/tmp.3CIfxaYzCK
[  FAIL LOG END  ] [ target/sonic-vs.img.gz ]
make: *** [slave.mk:793: target/sonic-vs.img.gz] Error 1
Makefile.work:224: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vagrant/sonic-buildimage'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've made all prerequisites as it is mentioned in build guide and I'm using 202006 release branch.

I have done some research before and I thought there may be some troubles with kvm. But when I try `sudo modprobe kvm-intel` on vm it says: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported`

Result from `dmesg | grep kvm`:

```
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 1:96fef001, primary cpu clock
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: using sched offset of 3780522329 cycles
[    0.000000] clocksource: kvm-clock: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
[    0.431418] kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 1:96fef041, secondary cpu clock
[    0.445819] kvm-clock: cpu 2, msr 1:96fef081, secondary cpu clock
[    0.460479] kvm-clock: cpu 3, msr 1:96fef0c1, secondary cpu clock
[    0.670955] clocksource: Switched to clocksource kvm-clock
[  111.115672] kvm: no hardware support
[10515.351145] kvm: no hardware support
[11873.537344] kvm: no hardware support
```

Result from `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nft_meta               16384  11
nft_counter            16384  15
nft_chain_nat_ipv4     16384  4
nft_compat             20480  4
nf_tables_ipv6         16384  4
nf_tables_ipv4         16384  5
nf_tables              69632  37 nf_tables_ipv4,nf_tables_ipv6,nft_chain_nat_ipv4,nft_compat,nft_meta,nft_counter
veth                   16384  0
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
iptable_mangle         16384  1
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              16384  6
ebtable_filter         16384  0
ebtables               32768  1 ebtable_filter
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
kvm                   561152  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
xt_conntrack           16384  3
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  5
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    40960  0
nfnetlink              16384  4 nf_tables,nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink
xfrm_user              32768  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  4
iptable_filter         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      20480  4
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  2 nft_chain_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_nat                 28672  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack          106496  6 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  13 ip6table_filter,xt_CHECKSUM,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,nft_compat,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,ebtables,ipt_REJECT,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype
br_netfilter           24576  0
bridge                122880  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
aufs                  217088  0
vboxsf                 49152  1
overlay                49152  0
isofs                  40960  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
vboxguest             286720  2 vboxsf
video                  40960  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
ib_iser                49152  0
rdma_cm                49152  1 ib_iser
iw_cm                  45056  1 rdma_cm
ib_cm                  49152  1 rdma_cm
ib_sa                  36864  2 rdma_cm,ib_cm
ib_mad                 49152  2 ib_cm,ib_sa
ib_core               106496  6 rdma_cm,ib_cm,ib_sa,iw_cm,ib_mad,ib_iser
ib_addr                20480  2 rdma_cm,ib_core
iscsi_tcp              20480  0
libiscsi_tcp           24576  1 iscsi_tcp
libiscsi               53248  3 libiscsi_tcp,iscsi_tcp,ib_iser
scsi_transport_iscsi   102400  4 iscsi_tcp,ib_iser,libiscsi
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 995328  0
raid10                 49152  0
raid456               106496  0
async_raid6_recov      20480  1 raid456
async_memcpy           16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              16384  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               16384  5 async_pq,raid456,async_xor,async_memcpy,async_raid6_recov
xor                    24576  2 btrfs,async_xor
raid6_pq              102400  4 async_pq,raid456,btrfs,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  1 raid456
raid1                  40960  0
raid0                  20480  0
multipath              16384  0
linear                 16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
mptspi                 24576  1
scsi_transport_spi     32768  1 mptspi
mptscsih               40960  1 mptspi
psmouse               131072  0
mptbase               102400  2 mptspi,mptscsih
e1000                 135168  0
```

Also I am using `6.0.22r137980` version of VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable nested virtualization which for a long time wasn't possible at all with the default provider for vagrant being virtualbox.

Once you enable nesting your reported issue should be resolved.
You'll find plenty of howto's on the internet, here a few to give you a start:

- [virtualbox](https://eclipsys.ca/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-virtualbox-new-feature/)
- [libvirt](https://nts.strzibny.name/inception-running-vagrant-inside-vagrant-with-kvm/)
- [vmware workstation](https://superuser.com/questions/800713/enabling-intel-vt-x-on-vagrant-guest)